# Problem displaying Polish characters in jQuery UI DatePicker Dialogie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, character-encoding

I seem to have a problem in displaying Polish characters in the jQuery UI DatePicker...
The Polish characters do not display correctly - they are replaced by question mark characters.
They work fine everywhere else in the page as the parent document's encoding is set to UTF-8.

Any suggestions?

Any help will be appreciated! :)

Thanks and take care!

Piotr.

Comment: No one can answer this since you didn't say what the problem was.

Comment: Edited, the problem is that the characters do not display correctly - they are replaced by question mark characters.

Answer (score 0):

if you are are using php you can try with this:

```
html_entity_decode('your content here', ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

or with jquery itself something like this might work:

```
var text = $("div#yourContent").html('your content here').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case with PT-BR.

You have a localization file to your datepicker right?
This file is the translation for the name of days and months.

Ok, **try replacing those character**, for an **html Special Character**
http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/web/codehtml.html

Example: ç for `&ccedil;`
ç is used in latin languages such as portuguese and french.

this problem shouldn´t happend, I guess it´s a bug in jquery or some miss option. Jquery should convert the characters to the charset of the page, but it´s not doing it.

Hope it can help.